# Why doesn't this xargs work?

Tags: unix, redis, xargs

I've been trying to get all of the value within a redis db, using redis-cli. 
This is done in principal by `redis-cli keys "*"` (returns all keys) and piping that to `redis-cli get` (returns the value of a key).

I've since discovered (on SO) a way to do it:

```
echo 'keys YOURKEY*' | redis-cli | sed 's/^/get /' | redis-cli
```

But before, I was trying this, and the get command never seemed to run. Am I doing xargs wrong?:

```
redis-cli keys "*" | xargs -0 -I % redis-cli get "%"
```

I appreciate that 'why didn't this work' questions are frowned upon, but I think the answer will be informative for people confused by xargs.

Comment: "why didn't this work" questions are the basis of all good stackOverflow Qs. But Qs without complete information are frowned upon, as you have neglected to show us an error messages or other evidence that "it is not working" ;-/, eh? Do you know what `-0` does for `xargs`? Check the man page. There may be other problems. Good luck.

Comment: It turns out that the -0 flag was the problem, which I included because some of my keys contain whitespace, and I erroneously thought that it would account for that. There was no further information because the second half of the command literally didn't output anything. `redis-cli keys "*" | xargs -0 -I % "%"` would output the list of key names, but including redis-cli get resulted in an empty output. There was no error message!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `-0` flag to `xargs`, which says that your input items are terminated by a null character (ASCII 0) rather than whitespace.  It is unlikely that the `redis-cli` command outputs keys in this format.  In fact, it seems to produce output that has one key/line, like this:

```
# redis-cli keys "*"
_tooz_group:central-global
_tooz_beats:38225c46-7ed8-4c2a-b1eb-6400d0f99004
_tooz_beats:bea903f7-ab5d-4503-be19-f2029beece93
_tooz_beats:bd859c91-0245-45cf-a289-23fc25998e97
_tooz_beats:04528af5-dd97-41af-87a6-d7dc0c0d9f5d
_tooz_beats:974b9d9d-86ff-457e-9a5c-e857ec12a915
_tooz_beats:a55cfe65-f344-4ed4-9b9f-a0ace4d8f6d3
```

If you drop the `-0` from your `xargs` invocation, it should work
fine:

```
# redis-cli keys "*" | xargs -I% redis-cli get %
```

If you have keys containing whitespace, this won't work (because
`xargs` expects your input data to be whitespace delimited).  In that
case, you can explicitly set the delimiter to `\n`:

```
# redis-cli keys "*" | xargs --delimiter '\n' -I% redis-cli get %
```

Comment: My keys do have whitespace, and I added the -0 flag as I thought it would fix that. The last of the options worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
# Set some data
redis-cli set mb1 A
OK

# Set some more
redis-cli set mb2 B
OK

# Check the keys we have
redis-cli keys "mb*"
1) "mb1"
2) "mb2"


#Retrieve those puppies, passing one at a time with "-n 1"
redis-cli keys "mb*" | xargs -n 1 redis-cli get 
"A"
"B"
```